# repeated measures four-way Anova lmer or ezAnova?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

can anyone help me to figure out what is the best way to run 4-way repeated measures ANOVA? I have four within-subject factors: Block, Reward, Congruency, and quan (quartiles). In addition, there a between-subject factor - Subject. I am using two different functions that result in slightly different results:

```
> anova(lmer(RTs~Block*Reward*Congruency*quan +(1|Subject) + (1|Block:Subject) + (1|quan:Subject) + (1|Reward:Subject) + (1|Congruency:Subject) +
         (1|   Block:Reward:Subject) + (1|Block:Congruency:Subject) + (1|Block:quan:Subject) + (1|Reward:quan:Subject) + (1|Congruency:quan:Subject)
       + (1|Reward:Congruency:Subject), av.ntile.stats)) # random effects

Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
                             Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F.value    Pr(>F)    
Block                             3       3     1  76.804    0.01 0.9029844    
Reward                           45      45     1 114.473    0.27 0.6062649    
Congruency                    13655   13655     1  63.512   81.07 5.942e-13 ***
quan                          92369   92369     1  71.000  548.40 < 2.2e-16 ***
Block:Reward                     15      15     1 146.379    0.09 0.7629624    
Block:Congruency                 67      67     1 203.053    0.40 0.5291229    
Reward:Congruency               683     683     1 160.338    4.05 0.0457577 *  
Block:quan                       12      12     1  71.000    0.07 0.7941806    
Reward:quan                     523     523     1  72.621    3.10 0.0823449 .  
Congruency:quan                 561     561     1  71.000    3.33 0.0722149 .  
Block:Reward:Congruency          30      30     1 307.243    0.18 0.6715647    
Block:Reward:quan               167     167     1 307.243    0.99 0.3203791    
Block:Congruency:quan           108     108     1 307.243    0.64 0.4247960    
Reward:Congruency:quan         1926    1926     1 307.243   11.43 0.0008145 ***
Block:Reward:Congruency:quan     14      14     1 307.243    0.08 0.7708619    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In another analysis I use ezAnova function which outputs less significant results:

```
> ezANOVA(av.ntile.stats, # specify data frame
                 dv = RTs, # specify dependent variable 
                 wid = Subject, # specify the subject variable
                 within = .(Block, Reward, Congruency, quan), # specify within-subject variables
                 detailed = TRUE, # get a detailed table that includes SS
                 type = 3)


> demoAnova2 <- anova_out(demoAnova,etasq="partial",print=TRUE)


$`--- FORMATTED RESULTS ------------------------------------`
                          Effect                                  Text
1                         Block F(1,23) =   0.22, p = .640, np2 = .01
2                        Reward F(1,23) =   7.85, p = .010, np2 = .25
3                    Congruency F(1,23) = 193.21, p < .001, np2 = .89
4                          quan F(1,23) = 272.62, p < .001, np2 = .92
5                  Block:Reward F(1,23) =   0.49, p = .493, np2 = .02
6              Block:Congruency F(1,23) =   0.01, p = .921, np2 < .01
7             Reward:Congruency F(1,23) =   1.16, p = .293, np2 = .05
8                    Block:quan F(1,23) =   0.03, p = .857, np2 < .01
9                   Reward:quan F(1,23) =   1.30, p = .265, np2 = .05
10              Congruency:quan F(1,23) =   1.47, p = .238, np2 = .06
11      Block:Reward:Congruency F(1,23) =   0.07, p = .789, np2 < .01
12            Block:Reward:quan F(1,23) =   0.38, p = .546, np2 = .02
13        Block:Congruency:quan F(1,23) =   0.51, p = .482, np2 = .02
14       Reward:Congruency:quan F(1,23) =   3.92, p = .060, np2 = .15
15 Block:Reward:Congruency:quan F(1,23) =   0.06, p = .806, np2 < .01
```

What is the most appropriate way to address 4-way repeated measures ANOVA?